# Mystified about making a PHP double-query dynamic list work. Using PHP 5.3.5

Tags: php, list, dynamic, double

I'm trying to create a dynamic list (5 row results) in php by first getting data from one table then using a resulting var to get the latest uploaded "image_links" (just 1 from each of the 5 artists) from another table -- then echo out.

The code here gives me the only one row with the latest image. When I comment out the "// get the latest image link uploaded ///" section of the code I get the 5 rows of different artists I really want but, of course, w/o images. I tried (among a bunch of things) mysql_result() w/o the while statement but that didn't work.

So what am I missing?

Thanks
Allen

```
  //// first get the artists followed  ////////////////
  $QUERY= "SELECT * FROM followArtist WHERE  user_id = $user_id "; 
    $res = mysql_query($QUERY);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($num>0){
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
         $artist_name = $row['artist_name'];
         $artist_id = $row['artist_id'];         
         $date_lastSent = $row['date_lastSent'];
         $date_artPosted = $row['date_artPosted'];
         $date_notePosted = $row['date_notePosted'];

//// get new notice data /////           
          if ($date_artPosted >= $date_lastSent) {
              $artp = "new artwork posted";
               }else{
              $artp = "";      
          }
          if ($date_notePosted >= $date_lastSent) {
              $notep = "news/announcement posted";
               }else{
              $notep = "";     
          }
          if ($artp!="" && $notep!="") {
              $and = " and<br />";
               }else{
              $and = "";       
          }
          if ($artp=="" && $notep=="") {
              $no = "No new images or news posted since your<br /> last visit, but we'll let you know when there is.";
               }else{
              $no = "";    
          }

 //////// get the latest image link uploaded ////////////////////////////////////
           $QUERY2="SELECT image_link FROM artWork WHERE artist_id ='$artist_id' AND make_avail = '1'  ";
            //ORDER BY date_submit DESC
            $res = mysql_query($QUERY2);
            $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
            if($num>0 ){
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                  mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                 $image_link= $row['image_link'];
                }   
 //////// end of get the latest images uploaded ////////////////////////////////                 
         echo "<tr align=\"center\" height=\"115px\">
                <td align=\"left\" width=\"15%\"> <a href=\"process_artist_idImages.php?artist_id=$artist_id&search=search\">
                                    <img src=slir/w115-h115/$path$image_link /></a></td> 
                <td align=\"center\" width=\"80%\"
                                    <span class=\"deviceMedLtGrayFont\">$artist_name</span>
                                    <br /><br />
                                    <a href=\"process_artist_idImages.php?artist_id=$artist_id&search=search\"/>
                                    $artp</a>
                                    <a href=\"process_artist_idImages.php?artist_id=$artist_id&search=search\"/>
                                    $and$no</a>
                                    <a href=\"process_artist_idImages.php?artist_id=$artist_id&search=search\"/>
                                    $notep</a>
                                    </td>
                </tr>";
        }  //// end bracket for getting latest image link
   } ///loop end for getting followed artist data
} ///end: if ($num>0) clause<code>
```

Comment: sorry for the lack of formatting. Seems to be hit or miss pasting between <pre><code>

Comment: On a side note, this is pretty evil looking code ... two things to look into, escaping variables before putting them into a query (SQL injection), and joining tables in SQL queries.  If you join the tables, you won't have to have two selects, just the one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read your code correctly, I see you looping using data from query1 in the control structure, and a lookup on query2 within each loop. You are reusing the variables in your loop1 control structure for query2 ($num and the query handle ($res)) for the second loop. Probably not desirable within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're sharing the variables $num and $res between the two queries ... your original properties will be overwritten when the second query is run.  Use different property names for the inner query.

Example of problem:

```
$result = QueryA();

while( $row = $result->getRow() )
{
    // -- You're overwriting the original result here ...
    $result = QueryB();

    // Next time the loop runs, it will run using the result from QueryB();
}
```

So change ...

```
    $res = mysql_query($QUERY2);
    $num = mysql_num_rows($res);

    if($num>0 )
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
            $image_link= $row['image_link'];
        }
```

to

```
    $res2 = mysql_query($QUERY2);
    $num2 = mysql_num_rows($res2);

    if($num2 > 0)
    {
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2))
        {
            $image_link= $row2['image_link'];
        }
```

Comment: It happens.  I really would consider some of the other suggestions in this post, the code is vulnerable to security problems, and somewhat  inefficient.  It reminds me of code from the PHP4 days, when all was innocent and unreadable :)

Answer (score 0):

this is a mess - as others have said you're using the same variables for different purposes.

That you're storing integers which seem to represent enumerations in a char field is bad.

You're iterating through the second result set to find the last record (from an unsorted result set!).

You only need one query - not 2.

```
SELECT f.artist_name, f.artist_id, f.dateLastSent....
   SUBSTR(
       MAX(
          CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date_submit, '%Y%m%d%H%i%s'), a.image_link)
       ), 15) as img_link
FROM followArtist f 
LEFT JOIN artWork a
   ON (a.artist_id=f.artist_id AND a.make_avail = '1')
WHERE user_id = $user_id
GROUP BY f.artist_name, f.artist_id, f.dateLastSent....
```